# "Error: No provider for Overlay!"

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

In my `Angular 2.0.0-rc.7` + `Angular Material 2.0.0-alpha.8-1` application built with `Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-1`, I get the following error after upgrading from `rc.5`+`alpha.7-4` (via the `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.8` NG CLI):

```
main.bundle.js:44545 Error: No provider for Overlay!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:7032:34)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44258:16)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:44289:16)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65311:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65339:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65302:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65111:21)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:45173:52)
    at ElementInjector.get (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:65475:48)ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.bundle.js:44545
main.bundle.js:44548ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ main.bundle.js:44548
```

My `package.json` dependencies are:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.7",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.21",
    "@angular2-material/button": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/button-toggle": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/card": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/checkbox": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/core": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/grid-list": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/icon": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/input": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/list": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/menu": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/progress-bar": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/progress-circle": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/radio": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/sidenav": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/slide-toggle": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/slider": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/tabs": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/toolbar": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1",
    "@angular2-material/tooltip": "2.0.0-alpha.8-1"
  },
```

and

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.11-webpack.9-1",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
```

My `main.ts` is:

```
import './polyfills.ts';

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';
import { AppModule } from './app/';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and here's my `@NgModule` definition in `app.module.ts`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    // other application-specific components...
    PageNotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MdButtonModule,
    // other MD modules...
    MdTooltipModule,
    OverlayModule,
    PortalModule,
    RtlModule,
    routing        // application routing
  ],
  providers : [
    Title,
    MdIconRegistry,
    // set of application-specific providers...
  ],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

Any ideas what this is all about?

Comment: please show your `main.ts`

Comment: I think you forgot to add provider for Overlay. Providers are the list of dependencies provider, the second parameter of bootstrapModule

Comment: Check your other modules if you have inject a dependency without setting a provider for it

Comment: It's true, @DanielTran, that I have not defined a provider for `Overlay`  -- see my updated question with my `@NgModule` definition. But what is the necessary provider?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I managed to eliminate this error by adding this to app.module.js:

```
import {OVERLAY_PROVIDERS} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
  imports: [...
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [OVERLAY_PROVIDERS],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

---

#### Edit (May 2018):

OVERLAY_PROVIDERS is now deprecated. use the OverlayModule instead

```
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
      OverlayModule
  ],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

Answer (score 7):

You should do `MaterialModule.forRoot()` (see the **UPDATE2**) that should fix the issue.

FYI That is the base maerial2 setup:

```
import { MaterialModule, MdIconRegistry, } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [MdIconRegistry],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

See more details here http://iterity.io/2016/10/01/angular/getting-started-with-angular-material-2/

**UPDATE1**: The official material2 doc has being updated so you might look in to this as well https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started

**UPDATE2**: In the latest [material2 (from 2.0.0-beta.2 and up)](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) no need to use `MaterialModule.forRoot()` any more  just use `MaterialModule` instead.

> The use of Module forRoot has been deprecated and will be removed in
>   the next release. Instead, just simply import MaterialModule directly:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        MaterialModule,
        ...
    ]
...
});
```

**UPFATE3:** Starting from version `2.0.0-beta.8` angular material depends on `@angular/cdk` so you need npm install that as well.

Answer (score 6):

For `@angular/material` version 6 and beyond: import `OverlayModule` in your root module (e.g. in `app.module.ts`). Importing in lazy-loaded module doesn't work! Details: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/10820#issuecomment-386733368

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by importing my own MaterialModule, which looks something like this

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {
  MdButtonModule,
  MdCardModule,
  ...
} from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    ...
  ],
  exports: [
    MdButtonModule,
    MdCardModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class MaterialModule {}
```

into the spec file, like so

```
import { MaterialModule } from 'app/material/material.module';
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [MaterialModule],
      ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`MdTooltipModule.forRoot()` should also solve your problem as it also includes `providers: [OVERLAY_PROVIDERS]`.

This is from [source](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/9954ca86ecac9f811a7c8aeb7b19e61fa89828eb/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.ts#L200-L207):

```
export class MdTooltipModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MdTooltipModule,
      providers: OVERLAY_PROVIDERS,
    };
  }
}
```