# "NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!" in console (Angular Material)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm getting an error when using Angular Material. Specifically,

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]:
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CdkConnectedOverlay -> Overlay]:
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Overlay!
    ...
```

(The full log can be seen below)

[image: Errors in Chrome DevTools Console]

The error above is logged in the Chrome DevTools console when I append the `ng build` command with the `aot` flag.

Searching on Google for the issue came up with a similar question from StackOverflow such as ["Error: No provider for Overlay!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480695/error-no-provider-for-overlay).

However, the answer in the question didn't work for me.

I'm also using the toolbar and drawer components from Angular Material.

Here's the `package.json` file:

```json
...
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/material": "7.2.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
  "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^2.1.2",
  "codemirror": "^5.39.0",
  "core-js": "^2.5.4",
  "ng-zorro-antd": "1.8.1",
  "ng2-codemirror": "^1.1.3",
  "rxjs": "^6.0.0",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
...
```

`app.module.ts`:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoadingBarRouterModule } from '@ngx-loading-bar/router';
import { OverlayModule } from '@angular/cdk/overlay';

import { LayoutModule } from './layout/layout.module';
import { PagesRoutingModule } from './pages/pages-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LoadingBarRouterModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    PagesRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    OverlayModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz?

Comment: You are using more than two modules?

Comment: My project is open source.And I use stackblitz open the version of github. https://stackblitz.com/github/Eve-1995/ng-series-study

Comment: You're using conflicting versions of Angular and Angular Material. Angular Material v7 requires Angular v7.

Comment: Are you also importing the necessary Angular Material modules into your main app module?

Comment: Actually,the previous version is V6.Both Material and Angular.But the error shows,then I guess maybe the high version could solve this problem.So I tried.But still not work.

Comment: Make sure when you install an npm package you look at its version and Angular compatibility. Normally, you can see that on every npm package page you want to install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using conflicting versions of Angular and Angular Material. (Your Angular dependencies are on version 6, while the Angular CDK & Angular Material dependencies are on version 7, which require Angular v7.)

You should either:

- Update all versions of Angular.

  This can be done by running `ng update @angular/core` which should update all Angular dependencies.

  *(For more info about the `update` command, check out the [docs](https://angular.io/cli/update), or the [Update Angular website](https://update.angular.io))*
- Downgrade your version of the Angular CDK and Angular Material.

  This can be achieved by running the following command:

  ```sh
  npm i @angular/{cdk,material}@'^6.0.0'
  ```

  This command should install version 6 of the CDK and Angular Material.

Comment: I have tried update my project.But one of my dependencies doesn't support V7.And privious version of my project,the cdk and material is v6.But the error still shows.

Comment: @Eve What's the dependency that doesn't support v7? Could you post the log?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the exact same error, due to lazy loaded modules which had the `mat-menu` component in them.

What removed the error for me, was including `MatDialogModule` and `MatMenuModule` in the `AppModule`, which isn't lazy-loaded:

```js
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
```

Then the error was gone, and the `mat-menu` worked again